# Getting error message when entering Chrome Webstore Item Id to old marketplace app

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

When I enter my Chrome Webstore Item Id in the settings for my old Google Marketplace app that I'm trying to migrate from, I get this error:

**"Vendor is not one of the owners of the current listing"**

I am following the instructions given here (See Step 3.):

https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2#heading=h.5oojrk7tttmq

I am logged in as the owner of both of the apps. This user is also the owner of the Project I have set up in Google Developer Console (http://cloud.google.com/console).

The new Chrome Webstore app is published (but only since very recently).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the user was not the owner (only member) of the API project used for the old app.
Problem solved!